Making sure BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler attaching access tokens
In my Blazor WASM app, I get 401 -Unauthorized status code when I call my backend API using the following code. How do I check to make sure a valid access_token is being attached to my API calls?
Here's Program.cs code:
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyApiClient",
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.test.com"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("MyApiClient"));

And in my service, I make an API call with this code:
public async Task<User> GetUser()
{
   // Set URL
   var url = "/account/info";
   var user = await GetAsync<User>(url);
   return user;
}

private async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
        return default;

    using (var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyApiClient"))
    {
        var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception("My API GET call failed. URL: " + url);

        var json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    }
}

Do you see anything that doesn't look right here? If not, how can I make sure a valid access_token is being attached to my API calls?
P.S. I see that the HttpClient is created correctly and the BaseAddress is correct in the error message I get. The error message is a standard unauthorized access error. I don't see any additional data in the error message, other than the url is definitely correct.
I also want to mention that I handle identity management and access tokens through Azure AD B2C. That setup seems correct as the user is able to sign in fine and the Id of the user is correct as well.
UPDATE:
A simple inspection of the HttpClient in GetAsync<T>() method shows that access_token is NOT being attached to the call -- as you can see in the following image DefaultRequestHeaders is null. It should have Authorization with value set to Bearer {access_token_value} -- see below.
At this point, I'm pretty certain this is a configuration issue. Also, please note that Blazor WASM "Stand alone" apps do NOT seem to get access_token's automatically and additional scopes are necessary for them to be included in the sign-in flow. I have not yet figured out what the correct config is and I will post it here when I do.


Hi Sam , try to use httpClient directly, like `private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
public MyService(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}`. Instead of using `IHttpClientFactory`.


Or you can try to add Authorization header manually, here is the sample code.

I believe this is a configuration error on my part but haven't yet figured it out. As per using HttpClient instead of IHttpClientFactory, the problem is that services are registered as Singleton but HttpClient is Scoped. This was the previous issue I was tackling and the solution provided here works well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79154604/1705266


How do I check to make sure a valid access_token is being attached to my API calls?

The easiest way to intercept an HttpRequestMessage is to add yet another DelegateHandler to your HttpClient. Something like this
public class RequestHeaderLoggerHandler(ILogger<RequestHeaderLoggerHandler> logger)
    : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.LogDebug(request.Headers);
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.LogError(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}

And the usage
builder.Services.AddTransient<RequestHeaderLoggerHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyApiClient",
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.test.com"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<RequestHeaderLoggerHandler>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

I haven't run this code so, I'm not 100% sure that the registration order is correct, maybe you need to first register the BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler and then RequestHeaderLoggerHandler.

Turns out a simple inspection of the HttpClient shows us if access_token is attached to a call -- see UPDATE in original post. Thank you for offering your approach though. It will come handy some day.

Hi @Sam, The BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler is an AuthorizationMessageHandler which does its work against HttpRequestMessage. So, your observation that the DefaultRequestHeaders is empty, is absolutely expected. As I suggested please try to add a custom DelegateHandler to intercept the outgoing HttpRequestMessage.

You could also use libraries like httpclient-interception for this purpose.
